# Tensorflow runtime determine the shape of Tensor

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Does Tensorflow support runtime determine the shape of Tensor?

The problem is to build a *Constant* tensor in runtime based on the input vector `length_q`. The number of columns of the target tensor is the **sum of length_q**. The code snippet is shown as follows, the length of `length_q` is fixed to 64.

```
T = tf.reduce_sum(length_q, 0)[0]
N = np.shape(length_q)[0]
wm = np.zeros((N, T), dtype=np.float32)

# Something inreletive.
count = 0
for i in xrange(N):
    ones = np.ones(length_q[i])
    wm[i][count:count+length_q[i]] = ones
    count += length_q[i]
return tf.Constant(wm)
```

**Update**

I want to create a dynamic Tensor according to the input `length_q`. `length_q` is some input vector (64*1). The new tensor's shape I want to create depends on the sum of `length_q` because in each batch the data in `length_q` changes. The current code snippet is as follows:

```
def some_matrix(length_q):
    T = tf.reduce_sum(length_q, 0)[0]
    N = np.shape(length_q)[0]
    wm = np.zeros((N, T), dtype=np.float32)
    count = 0
return wm

def network_inference(length_q):
    wm = tf.constant(some_matrix(length_q));
    ...
```

And the problem occurs probably because `length_q` is the placeholder and doesn't have summation operation. Are there some ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the [`tf.fill()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/fill) op is what you need. This op allows you to specify a shape as a `tf.Tensor` (i.e. a runtime value) along with a value:

```
def some_matrix(length_q):
    T = tf.reduce_sum(length_q, 0)[0]
    N = tf.shape(length_q)[0]
    wm = tf.fill([T, N], 0.0)
    return wm
```

Answer (score 0):

Not clear about what you are calculating. If you need to calculate N shape, you can generate ones like this

```
T = tf.constant(20.0,tf.float32) # tf variable which is reduced sum , 20.0 is example float value 
T = tf.cast(T,tf.int32)      # columns will be integer only
N = 10                       # if numpy integer-  assuming np.shape giving 10
# N = length_q.getshape()[0] # if its a tensor, 'lenght_q' replace by your tensor name
wm = tf.ones([N,T],dtype=tf.float32) # N rows and T columns
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
sess.run(wm)
```

Comment: Change the first line to "T=tf.constant(tf.reduce_sum(length_q, 0)[0], tf.float32), error occurs, "TypeError: Expected float32, got list containing Tensors of type '_Message' instead.". I know this code works when the constant is 20.0, how to deal with it when the reduce_sum for every batch input is different.

Comment: you have to mention the problem clearly to help you. where did u get the error ? what batch operation are you doing ?